# EventLog Source "Connect". No events in EventLog

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-event-log

I'm baffled by this, as I can find no documentation on wether or not "Connect" or "Connection" is some kind of registered keyword for EventLog Sources.

I'm trying to create an EventLog Source called either "Connect" or "Connection" through PowerShell.

```
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Connect
```

No Errors.

```
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -EventId 1234 -Source Connect -Message "Test write"
```

No Errors.

**But**

My Eventlog is empty for any events with ID 1234 from the Source "Connect",

I've tried with an arbitrary Sourcename like "MyCustomConnectionSource" which worked fine - no errors given, but an actual EventLog entry is created.

I would like some clarification as to why "Connect"/"Connection" does not work at all. (If anybody actually knows this or it's another MS mystery to be solved)

Thanks in advance

**Info:**
OS Version: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: Works for me without issue in Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise using source "Connect".

Comment: Interesting, it sounds like "Connect" may be some sort of reserved key word. Any reason why you wouldn't pick a more descriptive name in the first place anyways and just avoid the issue?

Comment: @LuckyLuke I thought the same - and did actually use another keyword, but wanted to know if anybody knew if it really was a reserved keyword - although i doesn't seem like it.